# How to stop captureOutput in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code, avcapturesession, avcaptureoutput

I found tutorial for working with QR codes - [here it is](http://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-reader-swift/). Using this method i can get image from device camera and find QR code there.

The problem is that when I change ViewController and even stop the AVCaptureSession - it seems that my camera is still working and device is searching for QR code. So how should I disable captureOutput method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I downloaded the demo project and doing

```
 self.captureSession?.stopRunning()
```

works just fine for me

fullCode

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

        // Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object.
        if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRectZero
            messageLabel.text = "No barcode/QR code is detected"
            return
        }
                self.captureSession?.stopRunning()
```

I set a breakPoint at the start of this function and it's not called anymore once the first QRCode is found.

Comment: That is working for me too, and if print captureSession?.running it equals to false. But when I put QR code behind my camera - it still notifies me that QR code is there.

Comment: @moonvader I updated the answer, if it doesn't help, can you post the exact code you use?

Comment: I found out what the was problem - your code is fine.

Comment: @moonvader Would be nice to post your "found the problem solution" - this is Stackoverflow where many have the same questions and are looking for the same answers...

Comment: As it was two years ago I can’t now definitely say now what was the issue. But it was my fault somewhere in running this code and not the problem with answer.